# How to normalize database column value when doing a comparison

Tags: knex.js

Let's say I have a table called "persons", which has the column "name".
One entry can have the name: "Amélie", another "GunTher".

I would be able to find "Amélie" and "GunTher" respectively in the database by matching with the comparing string "amelie" and "gunther".

Is there a way to craft a knex query where the values in the name column is normalized by my `normalizeString` function?

Answer (score 0):

```
const results = await knex('persons').where(knex.raw('lower(??)', ['name']), 'gunther');
```